# How to display a template based on a queryset done in a class based view where one of the argument for queryset comes from URL parameter

Tags: django

How to generate a template of all 'posts' that a 'user' wrote.

Idea: Client click on the 'user' link from the main site and we are taken to the page with all 'posts' user have generated.

I have tried so many things in views.py, part of them worked so only last not working solution will be attached. :)

I try to get a 'user' parameter from the URL so for example:

blogname/user -> that URL will generate list of all 'user' posts.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('author/<str:username>', AuthorPostIndexView.as_view(),
  name='author_post_index'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, unique = True)
    post = models.ManyToManyField(Post,blank=True,null=True, related_name='authors') 

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
# - commented out as non of these worked. Some of them I have broken
 playing around with desperation to fix so they are with lack logic,
 sketches. Tried those one by one. 


class AuthorPostIndexView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name ='authorpostindex.html'

#    def get_queryset(self):
#       username = self.kwargs['username']
#       authorpost = username.post.all()
#       return username


#    def get_queryset(self):
#        if self.request.method == 'GET':
#             queryset = Person.objects.all()           
#             url_username = self.kwargs('username', None)
#             if url_username is not None:
#                 queryset = queryset.filter(person__username=url_username).post.all()
#             else:
#                 queryset = "No queryset"


#    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
#     author = Person.objects.get(username=username)
#     authorpost = author.post.all()
#     return authorpost
```

authorpostindex.html

```
# Tried different solution depending from queryset, none worked.
```

Thanks

ps. Solution:

```
class AuthorPostIndexView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name ='authorpostindex.html'
    context_object_name = 'author_post'

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        queryset = Person.objects.get(username=username).post.all()
        return queryset
```

pss. Better one below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view should be based on Post. Then you can use all the existing logic of the view but additionally filter by the author username.

```
class AuthorPostIndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name ='authorpostindex.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = super().get_queryset()
       username = self.kwargs['username']
       return queryset.filter(authors__username=username)
```

(Note, it's a bit odd to store the username as a CharField on Person only. You should probably have a ForeignKey to the User model.)

Comment: Thanks for solution... Made me keep digging. I did not notice yours in the first place. I came with very similar which is attached at the end of the original question. Things I was doing wrong is trying to return own variable in get_queryset method like 'return authorpost' which I have changed to 'return queryset'. Also I set up context_object_name = 'author_post' in the view which help with looping on the template.